# Jquery show � symbol when fetching spanish accent from sqlite database

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova, utf-8

I have store some spanish data in sqlite database using phonegap. I have created a seperate JS file that will load the database at start. My HTML file contains meta tag  :

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

and I have called my database JS file like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/database.js"></script>
```

Now when I fetch data from sqlite db using a query, where ever spanish accent character is there it return me � symbol at that position instead of spanish character.

Its a simple phonegap app with manually created database and fetching data from that local db.

I am saving data like this :

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TEST (id, name, next_id) VALUES (547, "restín", 129)');
```

Fetching data like this using jquery :

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id = '+getID+'',[], DisplayShowDetails, errorCB);
}, errorCB);


function DisplayShowDetails(tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Name =  " + results.rows.item(i).name);
}
}
```

results.rows.item(i).name is returning me rest�n.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Wayy too broad.  Possibilities include everything from your database returning something that isn't utf-8 to the font you are using not supporting that character.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT hex(name) FROM test WHERE id=547`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a charset issue . Please check  whether database is returning data in utf8 and  also check whether the jquery which u are using sends the content type as utf8

Comment: are the columns in DB actually storing the spanish characters. can you check for the charset of column in which u are storing the data.

Comment: I am using eclipse and changed its encoding to UTF-8. (Project - Properties - Resource: Text File Encoding - Other [UTF-8]). But still no success :(